# could someone tell me why everything vibrates when the camera in my game moves?

Tags: camera, gml, game-maker-studio-2

I'm not sure why, but for some reason whenever the camera in my game moves, everything but the character it's focusing on does this weird thing where they move like they should, but they almost vibrate and you can see a little trail of the back of the object, although it's very small. can someone tell me why this is happening? here's the code:

```
x+= (xTo-x)/camera_speed_width;
y+= (yTo-y)/camera_speed_height;
x=clamp(x, CAMERA_WIDTH/2, room_width-CAMERA_WIDTH/2);
y=clamp(y, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2, room_height-CAMERA_HEIGHT/2);
if (follow != noone)
{
    xTo=follow.x;
    yTo=follow.y;
}
var _view_matrix = matrix_build_lookat(x,y,-10,x,y,0,0,1,0);
var _projection_matrix = matrix_build_projection_ortho(CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT,-10000,10000)
camera_set_view_mat(camera,_view_matrix);
camera_set_proj_mat(camera,_projection_matrix);
```

Comment: When I read the headline, I thought it is really vibrating (the controller). Maybe you should replace "vibrate" by "shake" or sth like that

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 options:

- Your game runs on a low Frames Per Second (30 or lower), a higher FPS will render moving graphics smoother (60 FPS been the usual minimum)
- another possibility is that your camera is been set to a target multiple times, perhaps one part (or block code) follows the player earlier than the other. I think you could also let a viewport follow an object in the room editor, perhaps that's set as well.

Try and see if these options will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If your camera is low-resolution, you should consider rounding/flooring your camera coordinates - otherwise the instances are (relative to camera) at fractional coordinates, at which point you are at mercy of GPU as to how they will be rendered. If the instances themselves *also* use fractional coordinates, you are going to get wobble as combined fractions round to one or other number.